# Ruby CSV: how to write nil fields as \N

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv

I want to write a CSV with ruby's default CSV library in order to use MySQL's fast import LOAD DATA INFILE.

Currently, when I enter nil for a field, it is written as `...;;...`, instead I want it to be `...;\N;...` (capital N for NULL, not to be confused with \n newline).

```
CSV.open(product_updates_file_name, "wb", {col_sep: ";", headers: false, force_quotes: false}) do |product_csv|
    product_csv << ["foo", nil, "bar"]
end
```

It currently leads to the decimal field being loaded as 0.00 in the database instead of NULL.

I know, I could set it NULL afterwards, but there are millions of rows and several columns affected, so I strongly prefere to write the CSV as MySQL expects me to:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `nil`'s `to_s` method like so:

```
class << nil
  def to_s
    "my nil placeholder text"
  end
end
```

All code using `to_s` will use this implementation for the value nil.

Comment: It is part of a huge rails app, so I would prefere a more local solution. Still, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the CSV-methods:

```
require 'csv'
class Array
  alias :old_to_csv :to_csv
  #Extend to_csv for usage like ["foo", nil, "bar"].to_csv( :col_sep => ";")
  def to_csv(options)
    self.map{|s| s.nil? ? '\N' : s }.old_to_csv 
  end
end  

class CSV
  alias :old_push :<<
  def <<(data)
    case data
      when Array
        old_push data.map{|s| s.nil? ? '\N' : s }
      else
        old_push data
      end
  end
end

#Testcode:
puts ["foo", nil, "bar"].to_csv( :col_sep => ";")   #--> [["foo", "\\N", "bar"]]
CSV.open('test.csv', "wb", 
      {col_sep: ";", headers: false, force_quotes: false }
  ) do |product_csv|     
    product_csv << ["foo", nil, "bar"] 
end 
#-> Creates test.csv with 'foo;\N;bar'
```

This works only, if you insert Arrays. If you insert other stuff, you must modify the logic.

---

Remark:
My first idea was to use a converter. But it worked only for parsing a csv, not for writing.

```
CSV::Converters[:nil_N] = lambda{|s| 
  s.nil? ? '\N' : s
}
p CSV.parse('foo;;bar', :col_sep => ";",  :converters => :nil_N)
#-> [["foo", "\\N", "bar"]]
```

Perhaps somebody else knows a way to use converters to build csv-files.

Comment: I also tried to work with converters at first and couldn't get it running. I'll try your other solution, thanks.